# Theorem 6 Corollary 2, Section 1.5 of Hungerford’s Abstract Algebra

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof, normal-subgroups

> If $f:G\to H$ is a homomorphism of groups, $N\lhd G$, $M\lhd H$, and $f(N)\lt M$, then $f$ induces a homomorphism $\bar{f}: G/N\to H/M$, given by $aN\mapsto f(a)M$. $\bar{f}$ is an isomorphism if and only if $\text{Im} f \vee M = H$ and $f^{-1}(M)\subset N$. In particular if $f$ is an epimorphism such that $f(N)= M$ and $\text{ker} f\subset N$, then $\bar{f}$ is an isomorphism.
>
> **Hungerford’s proof:** Consider the composition $f:G\to H$ and $\pi :H\to H/M$ and verify that $N\subseteq f^{-1}(M)=\text{ker}\pi f$. By [theorem 6 section 5](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4700360/861687) (applied to $\pi f$) the map $G/N\to H/M$ given by $aN\mapsto (\pi f)(a)=f(a)M$ is a homomorphism that is an isomorphism if and only if $\pi f$ is an epimorphism and $N = \text{ker} \pi f$. But the latter conditions hold if and only if $\text{Im} f\vee M=H$ and $f^{-1}(M)\subseteq N$. If $f$ is an epimorphism, then $H=\text{Im} f
> =\text{Im}f\vee M$. If $f(N)=M$ and $\text{ker}f\subseteq N$, then $f^{-1}(M)\subseteq N$, whence $\bar{f}$ is an isomorphism.

**My attempt:** We show $\bar{f}$ is a well defined function. If $aN=bN$, then $a^{-1}b\in N$. Since $f$ is homomorphism and $f(N)\subseteq M$, we have $f(a^{-1}b)=f(a)^{-1}f(b)\in M$. So $f(a)M=f(b)M$. Thus $\bar{f}(aN)= \bar{f}(bN)$ and $\bar{f}$ is well defined map. Let $aN,bN\in G/N$. Since $G/N$ and $H/M$ are group under multiplication $\cdot$ and $\circ$ respectively, and $f$ is homomorphism, we have
$$\bar{f}(aN\cdot bN)=\bar{f}(abN)=f(ab)M=f(a)f(b)M=f(a)M\circ f(b)M=\bar{f}(aN)\bar{f}(bN).$$ Thus $\bar{f}$ is homomorphism.

We show $\bar{f}$ is an isomorphism if and only if $\text{Im} f \vee M = H$ and $f^{-1}(M)\subset N$. $(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $\bar{f}$ is isomorphism. $\text{Im}f\vee M\subseteq H$ is trivial. Let $h\in H$. Then $hM\in H/M$. Since $\bar{f}$ is surjective, we have $\exists gN\in G/N$ such that $\bar{f}(gN)=f(g)M=hM$. So $f(g)^{-1}h\in M\subseteq \text{Im}f\vee M$. Since $f(g)^{-1}=f(g^{-1})\in \text{Im}f\vee M$, we have $h=f(g)f(g)^{-1}h\in \text{Im}\vee M$. Thus $H\subseteq \text{Im}f\vee M$. So $H=\text{Im}\vee M$. Let $x\in f^{-1}(M)$. Then $f(x)\in M$. So $\bar{f}(xN)=f(x)M=M$ and $xN\in \text{ker}\bar{f}$. Since $\bar{f}$ is injective, we have $\text{ker}\bar{f}=\{N\}$. So $xN=N$. Thus $x\in N$ and $f^{-1}(M)\subseteq N$. Hence  $H=\text{Im}\vee M$ and $f^{-1}(M)\subseteq N$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose $\text{Im} f \vee M = H$ and $f^{-1}(M)\subset N$. Let $hM\in H/M$, where $h\in H$. Since $M\lhd H$ and $\text{Im}f\leq H$, we have $\text{Im}fM=\text{Im}f\vee M=M\text{Im}f$, by [theorem 3 section 5](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4698344/861687). So $h=qm$, where $q\in \text{Im}f$ and $m\in M$. Thus $hM=qmH=qM=f(p)M=\bar{f}(pN)$. Hence $\exists pN\in G/N$ such that $\bar{f}(pN)=hM$. So $\bar{f}$ is surjective. Let $xN\in \text{ker}\bar{f}$. Then $\bar{f}(xN)=f(x)M=M$. So $f(x)^{-1}\in M$. Since $M\leq H$, we have $f(x)\in M$. That is $x\in f^{-1}(M)\subseteq N$. So $xN=N$. Thus $\text{ker}\bar{f}=\{N\}$ and $\bar{f}$ is injective. Hence $\bar{f}$ is isomorphism.

Suppose $f$ is an epimorphism, $f(N)= M$ and $\text{ker} f\subset N$. Let $hM\in H/M$, where $h\in H$. Since $f$ is surjective, $\exists g\in G$ such that $f(g)=h$. So $\exists gN\in G/N$ such that $\bar{f}(gN)=f(g)M=hM$. Thus $\bar{f}$ is surjective. Let $xN\in \text{ker}\bar{f}$. Then $\bar{f}(xN)=f(x)M=M$. So $f(x)\in M=f(N)$. Then $\exists n\in N$ such that $f(x)=f(n)$. Since $f$ is homomorphism, we have $f(xn^{-1})=f(x)f(n)^{-1}=e_H$. So $xn^{-1}\in \text{ker}f\subseteq N$. Which implies $x=xn^{-1}n\in N$ and $xN=N$. Thus $\text{ker}\bar{f}=\{N\}$. So $\bar{f}$ is injective. Hence $\bar{f}$ is isomorphism. **Is my proof correct?**

---

In last paragraph, I’m unsure of my proof of injectivity of $\bar{f}$. I think in following proof we don’t use $\text{ker}f\subseteq N$ hypothesis: Let $xN\in \text{ker}\bar{f}$. Then $\bar{f}(xN)=f(x)M=M$. So $f(x)\in M=f(N)$. Which implies $x\in N$. Thus $xN=N$ and $\bar{f}$ is injective.

Is proof of $\pi f$ is an epimorphism$\iff$$\text{Im}f \vee M=H$ trivial or similar to mine proof (which is kind of long)? If it is similar to mine, then author didn’t want to add details of proof.

Comment: This post seems like three different questions but each question depends on previous questions (except for first question, obviously). For instance author’s proof of third depends on result of second and $f$ is homomorphism is assumed in each question.

Comment: $f(x)\in f(N)$ does not, of itself, imply $x\in N$. It implies that there exists an $n\in N$ such that $f(x)=f(n)$.

Comment: Your proof is needlessly complicated. The composite map is surjective if and only if $\pi(\mathrm{Im}(f))= H/N$. The image of an arbitrary subgroup $B$ of $H$ under $\pi$ equals the image of $B\vee M$, and by the correspondence theorem, will be all of $H/M$ if and only if $B\vee M=H$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you so much for the answer. May I ask which theorem you’re referring to by “correspondence theorem”?

Comment: I don't have Hungerford with me. It's the part of the isomorphism theorems that establish an inclusion preserving correspondence between the subgroups of $G/N$ and the subgroups of $G$ that contain $N$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I googled correspondence theorem and found out it is theorem 11 section 5 (more general version of correspondence theorem) of Hungerford’s book which states “if $f:G\to H$ is an epimorphism of groups, then the assignment $K\mapsto f(K)$ defines a one-to-one correspondence between the set $S_f(G)$ of all subgroups $K$ of $G$ which contain $\text{ker} f$ and the set $S(H)$ of all subgroups of $H$. Under this correspondence normal subgroups correspond to normal subgroups”. Apply theorem 11 section 5 to $\pi :H\to H/M$. So $\pi (\text{Im}f)= \pi (\text{Im}f\vee M)=H/M=\pi (H)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin By injectivity of $\varphi :S_\pi(H)\to S(H/M)$, we have $\text{Im}f\vee M=H$. Since correspondence theorem comes after theorem 6 corollary 2 section 5, I assume we are not allowed to use correspondence theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your comments, I have an idea for that $πf$ is an epimorphism.

My attempts: $${\rm Im}\pi{f}=H/M \Longleftrightarrow\pi{\rm Im}{f}=H/M\Longleftrightarrow{{\rm Im}fM}=H$$
Since ${\rm Im}{f}$ is a subgroup and $M$ is a normal group, so we get that
$${\rm Im}f\vee{M}=H$$

Comment: By the way, there's no need to prove the injectivity of $\bar{f}$ again in the end.  The book told us that we just need to prove $f^{-1}(M)\subset{N}$. You can assume that if there exists $b\notin{N}$ which satisfys $f(b)=a\in M$, it will be a contradiction due to the conditions of $f(N)=M$ and $Ker f \subset N$.

Comment: Can you please show $\pi \text{Im} f= \text{Im} f /M=H/M\iff \text{Im} f M=H$?

Comment: Since ${\rm Im}f/M\subset{H/M}$ and ${\rm lm}f/M\subset{H}$, we just prove the opposite way. The conditions can translate into $\forall{h}\in{H},\exists{a}\in{Imf},aM=hM\Longleftrightarrow\forall{h}\in{H},\exists{a}\in{Imf},m\in{M},am=h$

Comment: I am sorry. It’s been a long time since I posted this post, I forgot what $M$ and $N$ are. $(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $\text{Im}f/M=H/M$. Let $am\in \text{Im}fM$. Then $\exists h\in H$ such that $aM=hM$. So $am=hm’\in H$, since $M\subseteq H$. Conversely, let $h\in H$. Then $\exists a\in \text{Im}f$ such that $aM=hM$. Since $e\in M$, we have $h=am\in \text{Im}fM$ for some $m$. Thus $\text{Im}fM=H$. $(\Leftarrow)$ is trivial. Obviously $\text{Im}\vee M=H$ follows from $M\lhd N$.