# Theorem 6 Corollary 4, Section 1.5 of Hungerford’s Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

> (Third Isomorphism Theorem). If $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of a group $G$ such that $K\lt H$, then $H/K$ is a normal subgroup of $G/K$ and $(G/K)/(H/K)\cong G/H$.
>
> **Hungerford’s proof:** The identity map $1_G:G\to G$ has $1_G(K)\lt H$ and therefore induces an epimorphism $I: G/K \to G/H$, with $I(aK)=aH$. Since $H = I(aK)$ if and only if $a\in H$, $\text{ker} I= \{aK \mid a \in H\}= H/K$. Hence $H/K \lhd G/K$ by Theorem 5.5 and $G/H = \text{Im} I\cong (G/K)/\text{ker}I = (G/K)/(H/K)$ by Corollary 5.7.

**Question:** I don’t understand following sentence in above proof: The identity map $1_G:G\to G$ has $1_G(K)\lt H$ and therefore induces an epimorphism $I: G/K \to G/H$, with $I(aK)=aH$. To be precise, use of identity map $1_G$ to define an epimorphism $I$. What is the purpose of identity map $1_G$?

I can show $I$ is well defined and epimorphism independent of identity map $1_G$.

**Edit:** As suggested by Professor Arturo Magidin I don’t need to rewrite proof of [Theorem 6 Corollary 2 Section 5](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4712851/861687).

Comment: And in doing that demonstration you are needlessly repeating the proof of the theorem [you just discussed](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4712851/742). The "point" is that you already did all that work in full generality, so you can invoke the theorem by applying it to the identity map, instead of *reproving the exact same thing* yet again. Sure you can show $I$ does everything directly. But you already havea theorem that does all the showing for you, so use it.